# Different variants of Mahabharta

Tags: scripture, mahabharata

We know Ramayana has many different versions ie the Ramcharitmanas and the most authentic Valmiki Ramayana. What about the Mahabharta are there any other retellings over Vysa how long are these?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes. Notable ones among them include

1. Gadugina Bharata by Kumara vyasa
2. Mahabharata tatparya nirnaya by Madhvacharya
3. Bharatamanjari by Kshemendra